# Insert break into string at N-th occurance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to find the "best" way to insert a break into a string of time so that it takes up two lines and always splits in the same place (e.g. Fri Nov 5 11:11 AM to Fri Nov 5 break 11:11 AM).

I do not want to change the width of the div that the string is inside of because an warning message will display there if no time is selected. I know I could split the string into spaces with .split() function and rebuild it into the string I want but I thought there must be a better way.

It would be nice to have a method to traverse (not necessarily divide) thought the string to find an element that occurs more than once. So you could do something like a vocabulary tool that changes the color of the next time(s) you used a word or something for fun like a ransom note generator, newspaper-clipping-like-letters, that uses different letter types for the same word.

For an example what I'm trying to fix is this but a generic solution would be nice.
[image]

Comment: So where exactly does it "always split in the same place"?

Comment: Please give us several examples so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: You could always do a character count, and insert a break if it hits your threshold value.


<code>
    var charLength = $(".text").length;
</code>

Comment: I added a picture of my problem.

Comment: The content should incorporate a non-breaking space character between  `8:00` and `AM`. In HTML, it's simply `8:00&nbsp;AM` which will prevent the time from being split incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var date = 'Fri Nov 5 11:11 AM'
date.replace(/(\w+ \w+ \d{1,2}) (\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} AM|PM)/, '$1 <br> $2')
```

This will split the string after 2 words and a `1 or 2-digit` number, if those are followed by `two` `1 or 2-digit` numbers separated by a colon followed by either `AM` or `PM`.

Answer (score 0):

**Prototype**

```
String.prototype.addLine = function(str, splitter) {
    var args = str.split(splitter);  

    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
       return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'? args[number]: match;
    });
};
```

**Usage** (for html replace `\n` with `<br />`)

```
var d1 = "Fri Nov 5 11:11 AM"; //Original format
var d2 = "{0} {1} {2}\n {3} {4}".addLine(d1,' '); //With the new line break
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

What you want to do is prevent times from being split from their AM/PM designators. Instead of trying to fix the script, the content itself should be changed such that a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_breaking_space) occurs between the time and the designator:

<sub>For example:</sub>

```
8:00&nbsp;AM
```

This will allow the content to fill its container fluidly, without separating the time from the designator with linebreaks.

If the content itself is meant to preserve whitespace (and therefore linebreaks), then the content should be styled to have:

<sub>In CSS:</sub>

```
white-space: pre;
```

or be contained within a `<pre>` element.

Or, if the content is *not* to be pre-formatted, but should always be broken to multiple lines, a `<br>` element should be used:

```
Fri Nov 5<br>11:11 AM
```

In this particular case I'd recommend using the `&nbsp;` entity instead of the `<br>` element, as the `<br>` element is meant for content that representationally requires multiple lines, such as with poetry or an `<address>`.

If you're not able to change the format of the text from the server, you could use `.replace` to insert a non-breaking space character with relative ease:

```
newStr = yourStr.replace(/(\d\d) ([AP]M)/g, '$1&nbsp;$2');
```

Here's a breakdown of the pattern: `/(\d\d) ([AP]M)/g`

- the RegExp literal is delimited by `/` characters
- parens are used to capture groups of characters, the `$1` and `$2` in the replacement string refer back to the captured characters.
- `\d\d` is used to match two consecutive digits, which represent the minutes in the time.
- a space is used to match the space between the minutes and the AM/PM designator. You may want to use `\s+` if there are multiple space characters in the HTML content.
- `[AP]` is used to match either the `A` or `P` character
- `[AP]M` matches `AM` or `PM`. This could have alternatively been written as (AM|PM)
- the `g` flag is used to tell the replacement to happen for every occurrence found in the string.